# Proving discontinuity

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity

> Assume set $A$ is countable and let$$f(x)=\cases{1 \text{ if }x\in A\\0\text{ if }x\notin A }.$$ Prove that $f$ is not continuous at $c\in A$.

I've seen such a problem before where $A=\mathbb{Q}$, so I tried the following. Assume $c\in A$ and pick $\varepsilon=1/2.$ Then, for all $\delta>0$ there exists (?) $x\notin A$ with $|x-c|<\delta$ but $$\left|f(x)-f(c)\right|=\left|0-1\right|=1>1/2=\varepsilon.$$

The problem with this proof is that I assume that between any two numbers there exists an $x\notin A$. In the case when $A=\mathbb{Q}$ this wasn't really a problem as between any two reals there is an irrational, but now I can't see how to prove that between any two numbers there is an $x\notin A$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note any interval $(c-\delta,c+\delta)$ is uncountable if $\delta>0$ .In fact it's homeomorphic (continuous bijection with continuous inverse) to $\Bbb R$.

Comment: @PVAL Why so? I understand that if this is true then $x\in (c-\delta,c+\delta)\implies \exists x\in B$ where $B$ is not countable. So there exists $x\notin A$, right?

Comment: If $(c-\delta,c+\delta)$ is uncountable it cannot be contained in $A$. This is the key fact to show there is some $x\notin A,x\in(c-\delta,c+\delta)$. I am not sure what your comment is showing. To show it is uncountable come up with a bijection between $(c-\delta,c+\delta)$ and $\Bbb R$.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming $A$ is any countable set in $\mathbb{R}$ and the topology is the standard topology.  $f$ is continuous on $A$ if and only if the inverse image of an open set in $\mathbb{R}$ is open in $A$. By Way of Contradiction, assume that $f$ is continuous on all of $A$.  So take the interval$$\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{4} \right)$$

We have that 
$$f^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{4} \right)=A $$

The inverse image of an open interval must by open in $\mathbb{R}$, but any open set can be written as the union of open intervals and every open interval is uncountable.  Therefore, $A$ is uncountable.  Contradiction.  Therefore, our assumption that $f$ was continuous on all of $A$ was incorrect.  Therefore, $f$ is not continuous on all of $A$.  I guess this answer just shows the existence of discontinuity, not that the function is discontinuous at any $c$ you choose.